# when performing a read command from within an xterm -e, it doesn't store the result of the read

Tags: bash, xterm

When running the following in `#!/bin/bash`

```
xterm -e "echo 123;read ANSWER;echo answer=$ANSWER;sleep 5"
```

I get these results in an xterm window (no matter what i type for the read).

```
123
answer=
```

So it does not ever store my input into the variable ANSWER.

I'm sure it's got something to do with running multiple commands from `xterm -e`.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the instance of bash, in which you are executing the xterm command, already resolves the `$ANSWER` variable before passing it to xterm.

Either escape the dollar symbol or use single quotes around the expressions. This appears to work in my case.

Update - syntax:

> xterm -e "echo 123;read ANSWER;echo answer=\$ANSWER;sleep 5"

or

> xterm -e 'echo 123;read ANSWER;echo answer=$ANSWER;sleep 5'

This is equivalent of your syntax if ANSWER is empty before xterm call:

> xterm -e "echo 123;read ANSWER;echo answer=;sleep 5"

As you can see the variable is resolved to the value and never enters the xterm. Also the bash running inside your xterm command is completly separated, variables or their values from inside cannot be easily passed outside it's scope.

Comment: Can you show me the syntax you're using?  I tried                                  xterm  -e "echo 123;read variable;echo '$variable';read pause"   and still didn't have any luck.

Comment: I did confirm that the variable is set before the xterm is called.  I set the var before the xterm, then read the variable a 2nd time within the xterm, and when i printed it out it contains the value set before the xterm was called.

Comment: Yes that is expected behaviour - before the call to xterm is made the variable is substituted by it's value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quoting problem:

```
xterm -e 'echo 123;read ANSWER;echo answer=$ANSWER;sleep 5'
```

You need the shell inside the `xterm` to see a literal `$` - not have it expanded by your current shell.